# Download all files in Google App Engine Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, export, blobstore

I've inherited a project which uses Google App Engine Blobstore to store files, and I need to download all the images so they can be migrated to a new system.

[image: Google blobstore]

I was able to get all the Google Datastore data out with https://github.com/jodeleeuw/export-google-datastore and was hoping there was something similarly easy with Blobstore. Or at least an example of how to read all the files in the blobstore and download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datastore solution you mentioned relies on the Datastore API being available for apps not running on GAE. But AFAIK the Blobstore API is not available outside GAE, so a similar solution is likely impossible.

I see a couple of options:

1. enhance the GAE app code you inherited by adding the capability to get the data in the Blobstore (since it normally should be able to) and export it either directly to where you want the data moved or in an intermediate place, say GCS for example, from where you can ship the data to the final destination easier. Moving directly to the final location would be preferable IMHO if you need to keep the app working with the new location - you can build a nice, hitless migration story
2. use the developer console Blobstore browser/viewer which also allows downloading and deleting the blobs, either manually or using a GUI automation tool (like selenium, for example) for a programmatic approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dan Cornilescu. Unfortunately, do to IP issues I can't see the original code base or make modifications to it for production. I'll leave the answer open for a bit, and if no one else replies I'll give you the green check box.